# How to prove that Gibbs state remains a gibbs state after evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Gibbs state is $$
\rho_G=\frac 1Z e^{-H/kT}=\sum_n \frac 1Z e^{-E_n/kT}|E_n⟩⟨E_n|.
$$.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_state), it is said that a Gibbs state is an equilibrium probability distribution which remains invariant under future evolution of the system. Does the Liouvillian there come from the unitary evolution of the system Hamiltonian (the $H$ in my equation above)?

Assume it is, but I do not see that it will remain a Gibbs state, for either the case of time-indpendent and dependent $H$.

Comment: $$i\hbar\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = [H,\rho]$$

Comment: @Count Iblis Is the $H$ the same as the $H$ in my question? What if it is different, say $K$ in the R.H.S of your equation?

Comment: @diff The $H$ in both equations is the same one — the Hamiltonian of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The density matrix is constant only when the evolution is Hamiltonian with the same Hamiltonian that is used in the definition. If some other Hamiltonian is used (for example, if some external perturbation is introduced), then the density matrix will evolve in non-trivial way.

So the "Gibbs state" will remain so only if the system is autonomous, i.e. no external forces act on it.

Answer (score 0):

The evolution of the system is govern by the Hamiltonian. Let the system is evolved from the initial state $\rho_{i}=\frac{1}{Z}\exp^{-\alpha H(t)}$. Here $Z=\mbox{Tr}\exp^{-\alpha H(t)}$ and $\alpha$ is the temperature of the initial state. Suppose the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ is varying in time. If $\rho_{f}=\frac{\exp^{-\beta H(t\rightarrow\infty)}}{\mbox{Tr} exp^{-\beta H(t\rightarrow\infty)}}$ is the equilibrium state corresponding to the Hamiltonian $H(t\rightarrow \infty)$, then it can be check that $[\rho_{f}, H(t\rightarrow\infty)]$=0. It means that $\rho_{f}$ is the stationary state for the Hamiltonain $H(t\rightarrow\infty)$.

Comment: What if the evolution of the system is not govern by the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Please look at this paper: Physica 43, 533 (1969).